# Form Validation using javascript . Accepting only text in text area

Tags: javascript, forms, function, validation

I am trying to use the following function to make my input text box accept only Alphabets, but the  problem is after saving this function the input box is not accepting anything not even alphabets. Whats wrong with this function??

```
    function Validation(){
var lastname=document.getElementById("last name").value;
if(!lastname.match("/^[a-zA-Z]*$/"))
{
    document.getElementById("errorbox").innerHTML="error: In Name field use alphabets only!";
    return false;
}
```

}

Answer (score 2):

You need to remove the quotes around the regex:

```
if(!lastname.match(/^[a-zA-Z]*$/))
```

And you can simplify the regex to make it case insensitive:

```
if(!lastname.match((/^[a-z]*$/i))
```

Note that your regex stricly accepts only unaccented letters. No accented letters, no hyphens, no spaces, which may be overly strict for a last name.